# c# exe and windows form

Tags: c#

I have a windows form application that contains a textbox. I want to open the windows form exe from another application (c# application) and write in the textbox from my form application. I have the following code. I don't see the text in my textbox .Why?

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Process myProcess = Process.Start(
        @"C:\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe");
    SetForegroundWindow(myProcess.Handle);

    if (myProcess.Responding)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(
            "This text was entered using the System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys method.");
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(" method.");
        //Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
    else
    {
        myProcess.Kill();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, textbox need to have focus.  Do textbox.Focus(); when the form is activated.  However, you may also look into extracting the Windows handle of the textbox itself, and then directly posting to the message queue.  This is usually how such things are done.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you writing an screen-scraping application?  Are you trying to programatically copy text out of another application?

Comment: no. i just wanted to have a little exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the correct window in which you want to place the text. You can do this through `FindWindow` and `FindWindowEx` combination. After that call `SetFocus` with the handle of that window as parameter. And only after that call `SendKeys` to send text data to that window.

Sample code would be something like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetFocus(IntPtr hWnd);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process myProcess = Process.Start(@"D:\OtherCode\Test\target\bin\Debug\target.exe");
    SetForegroundWindow(myProcess.Handle);
    IntPtr handleWindow = FindWindow(null, @"Target"); //In place of target, you will pass the caption of your target window
    if (handleWindow != null)
    {
        IntPtr hTextbox = FindWindowEx(handleWindow, IntPtr.Zero, null, null);
        SetFocus(hTextbox);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        SendKeys.SendWait("Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please tell me where to add this in my code? The exe file contains a form application with 3 textlabes . I just one to fill the first textlabel with a message. THX A LOT

Comment: ok..it adds in the first textbox. how do i search for my desired textbox if i have more than 1) and add a value to that specificate textbox.

Comment: You will have to keep calling `FindWindowEx` with 2nd argument as the previous handle until you reach  your text box.

Comment: how do i check the textbox reached is what i've want? can i write htextbox=="user2" (the name of the textbox desired: ore exactly the name of label besides the textbox where i want to add a text value).

Answer (score 1):

Move the form to a class library (dll project) instead an windows application (exe), and reference this in your new application. The thing you are trying is plain BAD!!!!

Comment: i don't understand. I just want to execute an .exe file. Using notepad is working perfeclty the code. Where am I wrong using another exe file (C# exe file)?Why do i need to use a dll?

Comment: I don't know why you're suggesting this, but having code in the executable is not a bad idea

Comment: @elisa & Kieren, I think that it is much better to place code in class libraries if it is used by more than one application.

Comment: i want to use the exe file:). Do you know what should i add in order to print the message in the text_box1?

Comment: but there is *no* code here that is being used by more than one application, I can't see where you think there would be code re-use?